# Dynamically sorting the table along with other few selection criteria via javascript and php

Tags: javascript, php, window.location

I have two parts

First part is building dynamic queries based on various inputs

second part is sorting the result table ASC / DESC

PHP part is well tested and working fine

```
if( !empty( $_REQUEST['cond1'] ) ){
  $sql[] =  mysql_escape_string( $_GET['cond1'] );
}
```

so on....

until last condition

build the query and get the records

Trigger for sort order is as follows

```
<table>
   <th><a href="orderby=name&obtype=A">Name</a></th>


</table>
```

When i click the href

all the selection criteria passed as GET PARAM is lost

Now the query is run only with SORT ORDER of the field.

How do i properly append the

```
orderby=name&obtype=A
```

To play around with window.location I am using the following function

```
  // Function gets a param value from a URL when given a param name
  function getUrlParameter( url, name ) {
      name = name.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
      var regexS = "[\\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)";
      var regex = new RegExp( regexS );
      var results = regex.exec( url );
      if( results == null )
          return "";
      else
          return results[1];
  }

  //Attaching Event handler for the heading and
  //finding what column heading is clicked

  $("#result-tbl th").click(function(ev){

    ev.preventDefault();

    // Build a URL from the orderbytriggered
    // Problem is when I click the first column it works
    // When i click the second, third, It keeps on adding all the order by
    // column which is not wanted.
    // Pls help me in finding the problem.
    var c = getUrlParameter( ev.target.href , 'orderby' ),
        d = getUrlParameter( ev.target.href , 'obtype' ),
        newurl = window.location.href + '&orderby=' + c + '&obtype=' + d;
    alert( newurl );
    window.location.href =  newurl;


  });
```

Answer (score 0):

The current GET PARAMS will be given to you in `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` .

Sample output for html:

```
<?php 
if ($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) {
    myQueryString = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] + "&orderby=name&obtype=A"
} else {
    myQueryString = "?orderby=name&obtype=A"
}    
?>

<table>
   <th><a href="<?=myQueryString?>">Name</a></th>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however     myQueryString = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] + "&orderby=name&obtype=A" since we are appending to $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] the same problem is happening sadddly :( Also i think we should not do with the Querystring rather somewhere else but i am not sure what to do.

Comment: The query string will contain all the get parameters you just used to generate the query. This sounded like what you wanted, if what you wanted was NOT to persist the get parameters please describe what you would like a VALID <a href> link to look. Can you print out what $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] is for your page load. For that matter, can you give us a listing for a print_r($_SERVER) and print_r($_REQUEST) before and after. I think you'll see that the parameters that you have in your $_REQUEST are actually coming from query string. If you want to persist without query string.Look into sessions